# Windows Certificates issue

Tags: .net, windows, wcf, windows-services, certificate

I have windows service (which starts WCF service inside) with some logic to read/verify installed certificates:

```
 public bool Verify(byte[] data, byte[] signature, string cert)
    {
        if (data == null || data.Length == 0)
            return false;

        if (signature == null || signature.Length == 0)
            return false;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cert))
            return false;

        IntPtr pStore = CryptoApi.CertOpenStore(CryptoApi.CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 0, IntPtr.Zero, CryptoApi.CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER, "MY");

        if (pStore == IntPtr.Zero)
            return false;

        bool ok = false;

        IntPtr pCertificate = CryptoApi.CertFindCertificateInStore(pStore, TypeOfEncoding, 0, CryptoApi.CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR, cert, IntPtr.Zero);

        if (pCertificate != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            IntPtr pContext = IntPtr.Zero;

            if (CryptoApi.CryptAcquireContext(ref pContext, null, null, (uint)CryptoApi.CRYPT_PROVIDER_TYPE.PROV_RSA_FULL, (uint)CryptoApi.CRYPT_ACQUIRE_CONTEXT.CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
            {
                IntPtr pHash = IntPtr.Zero;

                if (CryptoApi.CryptCreateHash(pContext, CryptoApi.CALG_SHA1, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref pHash))
                {
                    if (CryptoApi.CryptHashData(pHash, data, data.Length, 0))
                    {
                        IntPtr pPublicKey = IntPtr.Zero;

                        CryptoApi.CERT_CONTEXT certContextStruct = (CryptoApi.CERT_CONTEXT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pCertificate, typeof(CryptoApi.CERT_CONTEXT));

                        CryptoApi.CERT_INFO certInfoStruct = (CryptoApi.CERT_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(certContextStruct.pCertInfo, typeof(CryptoApi.CERT_INFO));

                        IntPtr pSubjectPublicKeyInfo = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(certInfoStruct.SubjectPublicKeyInfo));
                        Marshal.StructureToPtr(certInfoStruct.SubjectPublicKeyInfo, pSubjectPublicKeyInfo, false);

                        if (CryptoApi.CryptImportPublicKeyInfo(pContext, TypeOfEncoding, pSubjectPublicKeyInfo, ref pPublicKey))
                        {
                            ok = CryptoApi.CryptVerifySignature(pHash, signature, signature.Length, pPublicKey, null, 0);

                            if (!ok)
                                ok = CryptoApi.CryptVerifySignature(pHash, signature.Reverse().ToArray(), signature.Length, pPublicKey, null, 0);

                            CryptoApi.CryptDestroyKey(pPublicKey);
                        }
                    }

                    CryptoApi.CryptDestroyHash(pHash);
                }

                CryptoApi.CryptReleaseContext(pContext, 0);
            }

            CryptoApi.CertCloseStore(pStore, 0);
        }

        return ok;
    }
```

As I know, windows services work under Built-in administrator account, so when I go to install some cert, for example to the IE *(Internet Options -> Content -> Cetificates -> Other People)*.

[image]

the service doesnt see installed sertificates as it works with another Cert store (for built-in admin)(as I understand).

> In case I start Internet Explorer under Build-in admin (using PsExec
>   tool) - everything works excellent!

So, the question is - how to retrieve certificates under built-in which were installed under non-built-in admin!! Is it possible at all?

Comment: It is not using the built in admin account but the "Computer" account. You can get to the list via `mmc.exe -> File -> Add/Remove Snap in -> Certificates -> Computer Account -> Local Computer`

Answer (score 0):

After additional investigations I decided that this is impossible. Built-in admin account has different storage and there is no way to reach another storage.

Comment: The other storage are stored in the local user registry for the other user. So yes, if the user's registry is not loaded you can't access it, that is why if you are going to be using a certificate with a service it must be installed under the system account.